# Concurrent increment g = g + 1 of a static variable appears atomic, but shouldn't be?

Tags: c#, monitor

Can't find why code below with commented `Monitor` works like synchronized while writing to to `g` and always returns `g=50`. I was expecting some discrepancy an result less than `50`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace _7_monitor
{
    class Program
    {
        static object sync = new object();

        static int g = 0;

        static Barrier b = new Barrier(6, (b) => { Console.WriteLine("barier reached"); } );

        public static void tjob(object obj)
        {
            int t = (int)obj;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                //Monitor.Enter(sync);
                g = g + 1;
                //Monitor.Exit(sync);

                Console.WriteLine("thr {0} iter={1}", t ,  i);
            }
            b.SignalAndWait();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Thread d = new Thread(tjob);
                d.Start(i);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("waiting");
            b.SignalAndWait();

            Console.WriteLine("g={0}",g);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The short answer is 'you got lucky'. The operation (of reading, incrementing and setting an integer) is so fast that the race condition where the bug surfaces is very rare. You haven't run it long enough to hit the race condition. I've written similar bugs in the past where such a bug might take **weeks** to actually be seen.

Comment: *for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)* is too much short. There is a good possibility that the second thread hasn't started that the first one has finished. There is a (quite) big overhead in creating and starting a thread, surely bigger than doing 20 additions (`i` and `g`)

Comment: Also note that you have captured a modified closure where you're passing the loop variable to the thread.

Comment: And the preferred alternative is `System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref g);`

Comment: I would agree with @mjwills. 
Instead of a Monitor you could also use a lightweight Interlocked.Increment method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out, a loop of 10 will complete so quickly that there's a good chance that the other threads haven't even started yet, so you've likely got sequential access to the global static variable `g`, in any event, hence the apparantly observed consistent result.

With a longer loop (I've taken some of the fluff out) with no protection around `g`, we do get something resembling a random number generator.

```
var threads = new List<Thread>();
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var d = new Thread(x => {
        for (var loop = 0; loop < 100000; loop++)
        {
            // unsynchronized mutation
            g = g + 1;
        }
    });
    d.Start(i);
    threads.Add(d);
}
foreach (var t in threads)
{
    t.Join();
}

Console.WriteLine("g={0}", g); // 158609, 173331, 127983, ... (i7 with 4 HT Cores)
```

As per @Jurgis' comment, instead of a `Monitor` or `lock`, [Interlocked.Increment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has been provided to .Net

Replacing `g = g + 1` with `Interlocked.Increment(ref g);` returns the expected:

> g=500000

(and obviously, in the real world, there would be absolutely no point in parallelizing work which would just contend for a shared variable)